# How large data can Python Ray handle?

Tags: python, ray

Python Ray looks interesting for machine learning applications. However, I wonder how large Python Ray can handle. Is it limited by memory or can it actually handle data that exceeds memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It currently works best when the data fits in memory (if you're on a cluster, then that means the aggregate memory of the cluster). If the data exceeds the available memory, then Ray will evict the least recently used objects. If those objects are needed later on, they will be reconstructed by rerunning the tasks that created them.